# Ember Data: Loading comments for a post from separate endpoint

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two endpoints of interest:
/posts -> to get all the posts
/posts/{post_id}/comments -> to get all the comments for a post

I would like to have a comments attribute on the post model, populated with comments from the comments endpoint. How can I load comments into the posts?

I am using DS.JSONSerializer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your model a `hasMany` property:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
    comments: hasMany('comment');
});
```

And set in your `Post` payload the comments relation as a [related link](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-links):

```
data: {
    attributes: {}
    id: 'your-post-id',
    relationships: {
        comments: {
            links: {
                related: 'posts/your-post-id/comments'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as you target the comments, Ember Data will do a call to your related link. E.g:

```
{{#each post.comments as |comment|}}
    {{comment.propertyX}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I have little control over the API, and it doesn't conform to the JSONAPI spec.

Comment: Then you need to write custom serializers to change the backend payload to the JSONAPI spec. Read this whole article: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/customizing-serializers/